# What are examples of "other" page story types in the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

When I make a request to get a break down for a day/week/month of the page stories, I get something like:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "name": "page_stories_by_story_type",
  "period": "day",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": {
        "checkin": 3,
        "page post": 102,
        "other": 1835,
        "fan": 1233,
        "user post": 0,
        "question": 0,
        "coupon": 0,
        "event": 0,
        "mention": 0
      },
      "end_time": "2016-11-02T07:00:00+0000"
    },
  ....
  ]
 }
}
```

What I can't figure out is what kind of story falls into "other"?